# Sonata sandbox 2.3 installation failed

Tags: symfony, composer-php, sonata

I'm trying to install Sonata Sandbox, but theire is always a problem. 
When I launch the command: 
php composer.phar create-project sonata-project/sandbox:2.3.x-dev, or download the project with git and run a composer intsalll

it ends by:

```
[ErrorException]
ZipArchive::extractTo(vendor/composer/d4ef55a3/sonata-project-SonataAdminBu
ndle-68a836e\Resources\public\vendor\x-editable\dist\jquery-editable\jquery
-ui-datepicker\css\redmond\images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png): failed t
 o open stream: No such file or directory
```

And I can't find how to solve this issue.

Comment: maybe composer self-update helps

Comment: Thank you but my composer is up to date

Answer (score 0):

To avoide those problem try to resolve them one by one.In your Composer.json try to add dependencies one by one. At First remove all requirements and keep only one and execute composer update, then every time composer told you to add some requirement add them.Try this step by step and it should  resolve the problem.